# JAVA_HOME set wrongly

Tags: java, java-8, java-home

When I do echo $JAVA_HOME
,
I get /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

But When I do /usr/libexec/java_home,
I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

I think both of them should return
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
but $JAVA_HOME doesn't return that.

I put
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) in .bash_profile.
What's my issue? how to change JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I switched to [sdkman!](http://sdkman.io/) I suggest you do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems with your setup and commands. Execute the following commands:

```
$ cd ~
$ vi .bash_profile
```

Put the following line in this file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Save and exit the file and then execute the following commands:

```
$ source .bash_profile
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Now, you should be able to get the results correctly.

**Regarding setting Java-8:**

Execute the following command:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

This should print all JDK versions installed in your system. Now, copy the exact version number of Java-8 (e.g. 1.8.0_181) from the list and execute the following command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_181)
```